# How do I find a good job for my Sim in Sims 3 pets?

Tags: the-sims-3

I read the newspaper every time it comes on Sims 3 pets and I get jobs that don’t suit my characters. What do I do? My character is really handy, lv. 8, yet I don’t know what to do. I go to places, but not one that’s for his handy skill. I’m worried that my Sim family will be poor because he can’t find a good job. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What jobs are you looking for exactly? A "good job" could mean many different things depending on the reader.

Comment: Please do not edit your question into a completely different one.

Comment: Okay. I can’t ask more questions, that’s the only reason.

Comment: So basically you want a "pet" related job, and since your character already has high leveled skills, you want to get a high end/high graded job instead of one of the starting jobs?

Comment: Yes. That’s exactly what I want

Comment: Do you know how to get a job like that?

Comment: I don’t know how to get a job for my pet, besides being a police dog.